# Protobuf ParseFromZeroCopyStream incurs high memory usage with repeated field

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers

I have encountered a problem of high memory usage when using `ParseFromZeroCopyStream` to load file in which a large buffer is written. Besides, the code snippet below uses 60Gb++ of RAM but failed as the system froze after reaching its RAM limit.

FYI, I am using protobuf as DLL.

***scene.proto***

```
syntax = "proto3";

package Recipe;

option cc_enable_arenas = true;

message Scene
{
    repeated int32 image_data = 1 [packed=true];
}
```

***source.cpp***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include "Scene.pb.h"
#include <google\protobuf\io\zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
#include <google\protobuf\io\gzip_stream.h>
#include <google\protobuf\arena.h>

int const _MIN = 0;
int const _MAX = 255;
unsigned int const _SIZE = 1280000000;
//unsigned int const _SIZE = 2000;
unsigned int const _COMPRESSION_LEVEL = 6;


void randWithinUnsignedCharSize(uint8_t * buffer, unsigned int size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = i;
    }
}

using namespace google::protobuf::io;

int main()
{
    GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

    {
        google::protobuf::Arena arena;

        Recipe::Scene * scene = google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMessage<Recipe::Scene>(&arena);
        uint8_t * imageData = new uint8_t[_SIZE];
        randWithinUnsignedCharSize(imageData, _SIZE);
        scene->mutable_image_data()->Resize(_SIZE, 0);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _SIZE; i++)
        {
            scene->set_image_data(i, imageData[i]);
        }
        std::cout << "done saving data to repeated field.\n";
        {
            std::fstream output("data.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
            OstreamOutputStream outputFileStream(&output);
            GzipOutputStream::Options options;
            options.format = GzipOutputStream::GZIP;
            options.compression_level = _COMPRESSION_LEVEL;

            GzipOutputStream gzipOutputStream(&outputFileStream, options);

            if (!scene->SerializeToZeroCopyStream(&gzipOutputStream)) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to write scene." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
        delete[] imageData;
    }
    std::cout << "Finish serializing into data.txt\n";
    {
        google::protobuf::Arena arena1;
        Recipe::Scene * scene1 = google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMessage<Recipe::Scene>(&arena1);
        {
            std::fstream input("data.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
            IstreamInputStream inputFileStream(&input);
            GzipInputStream gzipInputStream(&inputFileStream);
            if (!scene1->ParseFromZeroCopyStream(&gzipInputStream)) {
                std::cerr << "Failed to parse scene." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }

        std::cout << "scene1->imagedata_size() " << scene1->image_data_size() << std::endl;
    }

    google::protobuf::ShutdownProtobufLibrary();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not the answer you wanted to hear, but protocol buffers [were not designed to wrap large amounts of data](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/techniques#large-data). They are intended to be used for command-and-control, with raw data streams exchanged by other means; or for large data streams consisting of small proto messages.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, hi,sorry for the very late reply, so what i could do is wrapping those large data into multiple messages?

Comment: I would suggest designing a data format that doesn't involve placing image data inside a proto message. E.g. you could have a proto describing some metadata (e.g. image dimensions, or whatever your application needs) followed by raw image data (again, not wrapped in a message). Or something along these lines. Nothing says the whole file must be one big proto.

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik, I have solved the problem by splitting the big buffer to be stored in multiple small messages. However, now i am getting the error of `exceeded maximum protocol size of 2GB`

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik, i understand that things can go into different proto, but it is one of my requirement that to have one proto that contains the whole thing.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what you expect to hear. You've kind of painted yourself into a corner. You need a thing larger than 2GB stored in a single proto, but a single proto can't be larger than 2GB. One of these restrictions has to give - and guess what, it's not going to be the 2GB limit. I suppose you'll have to figure out whether those requirements of yours [are more what you call "guidelines"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jl0hMfqNQ-g)

Comment: Hi @IgorTandetnik, ya, i agreed with what you said. Then splitting proto would be the only way to go. Can i know why 2GB is the limit?